# PSpice Error subcircuit internal node floating

Tags: pspice, subcircuit

I am trying to simulate a circuit with a variable capacitor in PSpice.
The circuit is a simple test circuit like this:

[image]

And the VARICAP model description is this:

```
*PSpice Model Editor - Version 16.6.0

*$

.SUBCKT VARICAP 1 2 CTRL

R1 1 3 1u

VC 3 4

EC 4 2 Value = { (1/v(ctrl))*v(int) }

GINT 0 INT Value = { I(VC) }

CINT INT 0 1

.ENDS

*$
```

Running the simulation gives me this error `("ERROR(ORPSIM-15142): Node X_U1.int is floating")`, which indicates that the internal node `INT` in the `VARICAP` component is floating. Usually this error shows up when a node does not have a DC path to GND. How is this possible to fix in the subcircuit description?

PS: The theory behind the circuit is described here: [VARICAP](http://powerelectronics.com/site-files/powerelectronics.com/files/archive/powerelectronics.com/mag/504PET07.pdf)

Comment: The standard workaround is to add a very high value resistor (100 Mega ohm or more) between that floating node and ground. I use a smarter simulator (Cadence Spectre) which does that automatically using 1 Tera Ohm resistors)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the standard workaround is just like that. My problem was that an internal node inside a component had this floating node error.
The solution was the same, just in PSpice SUBCKT syntax. The working model looks like this:

.SUBCKT VARICAP2 1 2 CTRL

R1 1 3 1u

R2 2 INT 1G

VC 3 4

EC 4 2 Value = { (1/v(ctrl))*v(int) }

GINT 0 INT Value = { I(VC) }

CINT INT 0 1

.ENDS

Notice R2 is the high value resistor connected from INT (the internal node) to 2 (external node).

Cheers, Wolfgang.